# how to merge entity reference relationship field value

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I am facing problem in drupal views.
In my view display table having relationship with other entity type.
I am not getting desire output. It show duplicate rows with same title due to entity relationship.

I wanted to aggregate entity relationship field with ",".

I already try some module like : view distinct, views_merge_rows.

But did not work for me.

Please suggest some module.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) and if you cant do it in the database [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) gives you even more options.